# Cannot find -ltinfo when compiling android 4.0.3

Tags: android, build, compiler-errors

Hi I have got a problem that I can't solve when compiling the android source for ICS.  The build gets to a certain stage, then I get the message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libtinfo.so when searching for -ltinfo
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../libtinfo.a when searching for -ltinfo
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libtinfo.so when searching for -ltinfo
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libtinfo.a when searching for -ltinfo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltinfo
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/adb_intermediates/adb] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have tried updating/installing libncurses5-dev and libtinfo-dev which were both latest versions and am a bit stuck now.  How can I get rid of this to allow the build to happen properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had seen similar issue with gingerbread when compiled on 64bit ubuntu. It got fixed with installation of lib32ncurses5-dev and its dependencies which includes lib32tinfo5-dev. The compiled host adb executable with android is a 32-bit executable.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen same problem on my fedora 16 64bit, same android branch 4.0.3 r1
you might want to try ncurses-devel.i686
yum install ncurses-devel.i686

it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue while I was building mysql statically. So I had to install the static versions of these libraries. For example I did run:

```
yum search ncurses
```

Then I installed,

```
yum install ncurses-static # not exactly the same syntax, but something similar; see search command's output
```

Answer (score -1):

This might work in Fedora 23

`dnf install ncurses-devel`